# Network calls show Error Message on Screen with setFailSilently()

Tags: codenameone

I'm using the network calls and adding the following statements before reading the response.

```
 r.setReadResponseForErrors(true);
 r.setFailSilently(true);
 NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
```

I don't want to show network error on Mobile App to the user but want to read the response code and perform the operation accordingly. Does this order matters? or do I have to setFailSilently() before setReadResponseForErrors? Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned this in another question where I literally quoted the code of fail silently...

You probably have a network manager listener probably in your init method where you show a generic error. That's part of the application boilerplate code.